# Running external php script from another external php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

i have my main index page which uses an ajax request to an external php file which handles the user login data. In that external php file i also include another external php file which handles all the functions, however the external login file is not able to use any of the functions

Here is the ajax call from index.php

```
$('#ind_login_submit').on('click', function (e) {

    var vars = $("#ind_login_form").serialize(); // the script where you handle the form input.
    //alert("gu");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "scripts/index/ind_login_submit.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            for(var obj in data){
                if(obj == "error"){
                    alert(data[obj]);

                }else if(obj == "success"){
                    alert(data[obj]);
                    window.location.replace("http://localhost/site/dashboard.php");
                }
            }
            //alert(hr.responseText);
            //location.load();
        }
    };
    hr.send(vars);
    //results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the external ind_login_submit.php

```
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
 session_start();
   include '../../connect.php';
    include '../functions.php';
    $secret_key = '';
globalSecret($secret_key);
$error_array = array('error' => $secret_key);
            $jsonData = json_encode($error_array);
            echo $jsonData; 
            exit;

if(isset($_POST['ind_login_remember'])){

    $ind_login_remember=1;
}else{

    $ind_login_remember=0;
}



$ind_login_email = $_POST['ind_login_email'];
$ind_login_password = $_POST['ind_login_password'];
```

And here is the functions.php

```
function globalSecret(){

$secret = "This is the secret";
$secret_key = sha1($secret);
}
```

When i run the code i just get a blank alert show, where it should show the $secret_key variable

Comment: Track the request in your network log. What is the response from PHP? Forget alerts for now - this is your first debugging port of call.

Comment: you dont do anything with $secret_key in the function, did you forget the `return` or perhaps `echo`

Comment: Like @Dagon suggested you need to return your `$secret_key`. The function seems to be a `void` function.

Comment: also you parse a variable to the unction which you don't use, get the basics right before going fancy.

Comment: You're also calling the function with the wrong number of arguments. It doesn't take any arguments, but you're passing `$secret_key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the line

```
globalSecret($secret_key);
```

should be

```
$secret_key = globalSecret();
```

and the function globalSecret() should be as follows:

```
function globalSecret(){
    $secret = "This is the secret";
    $secret_key = sha1($secret);
    return $secret_key;
}
```

Comment: And he needs to return something from the function.

Comment: wont do anything, as `globalSecret` returns nothing

Comment: Okay that works perfect now, i completely forgot about returning it, just thought that it would magically send the variable back

Comment: i believe perl will automatically return the last calculated value but in php you have to do it explicitly